# Interesting Way to Format an Error, but recode for it at the same time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this function that says lookup this value, x, and return another value, y, that is linked to value x.

However not all the time it comes up. Thus it gets recoded as `N/A`. So I used an `IFERROR` function that says if there is an error, recode as `0`.

Is there a way in which I can do that but also color the cell and certain color. I looked into Conditional Formatting and it seemed to only be values or Text, but the cell wont be text after the if function executes.

Comment: will that still work when I go to add things up?

Comment: You can put the same formula into CF and replace `IFERROR` with `ISERROR`.  This will return true on bad cells which you can then format.  If the calculation is not crazy and won't change, this works well enough.  Regarding the `SUM` on `"0"` recommended by @pnuts, a `"0"` is skipped over and does not affect the total.  You will get odd formatting by default with text being left aligned and number right aligned, but that is easy to overwrite.

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether you are summing *0* or *"0"*. Neither is going to change the total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set things clearer, I've arranged a set of example:

This is the MASTER Table
**A1:A4** is named as **NUM_L** and then, 
**B1:B4** is named as **SAY_L**

```
     A        B
1  Number   Say_it
2   1       One
3   2       Two
4   3       Three
```

And then this is the TRANSACTION Table

```
      G       H
1  Sample   Say_it
2   2       Two
3   0       NOPE
4   2       Two
5   6       NOPE
6   3       Three
```

This is my formula for H1 Cell:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(SAY_L; MATCH(G2; NUM_L; 0))); "NOPE"; INDEX(SAY_L; MATCH(G2; NUM_L; 0)))
```

so, the number that is not in 1 or 2 or 3 will be written as "NOPE"

at the conditional formatting for cell H1

i can put this:

```
=ISERROR(INDEX(SAY_L; MATCH(G2; NUM_L; 0)))
```

and color it YELLOW background cell, when condition has been met

It's all working

Isn't it this result what you really want to achieve?